# codeigniter routing wont route correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter and i'm doing a project now..
I have a home controller which controlls all the pages and it is working fine.
The website contains an article page where it displays all the articles and if some one clicks on the read more it will redirect to article details page

The problem is if i click the read more link (eg : http://example.com/articles_details/2/sample-slug) on the articles page, it automatically redirects to http://example.com/articles_details/2  .... can somebody help me to fix this.

below is the details of my project files

**Folder structure**

```
website_folder/ 
–––– application/
---------- controllers/
---------------- admin/
---------------- home.php
---------- views/
---------------- templates/
--------------------- articles.php
--------------------- article_details.php
---------------- _main_layout.php
–––– assets/ 
–––– system/ 
---- .htaccess 
–––– index.php
```

**home controller**

```
class Home extends Frontend_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }   

    public function index()
    {
        $slug = $this->uri->segment(1) ? $this->uri->segment(1) : 'home';
        $this->data['page'] = $slug;

        $method = '_'.$slug;

        if(method_exists($this,$method))
        {
            $this->$method();
        }
        else
        {
            show_error('Could not load template '.$method); 
        }

        $this->data['subview'] = $slug;

        $this->load->view('components/page_head');
        $this->load->view($layout,$this->data);
        $this->load->view('components/page_tail');
        $this->load->view('components/'.$script); 
    }

    private function _home()
    {
        //fetch datas to be shown in homepage
    }

    private function _articles()
    {
        //fetch datas to be shown in article page
    }

    private function _article_details()
    {
        //fetch datas to be shown in article detail page
        $aid = $this->uri->segment(2);
        $query =  $this->db->query("select * from articles where id = ".$aid);
        $this->data['articledetails'] = $query->row();
        count($this->data['v']) || show_404(uri_string());
        $rslug = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $sslug = $articledetails->slug;
        if($rslug != $sslug)
        {
            redirect('article_details/'.$aid.'/'.$sslug,'location','301');
        }
    }

}
```

**routes.php**

```
$default_controller = "home";
$controller_exceptions = array('admin');

$route['default_controller'] = $default_controller;
$route["^((?!\b".implode('\b|\b', $controller_exceptions)."\b).*)$"] = $default_controller.'/index/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

**Htaccess File**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

**articles.php (views file)**

```
<div id="articles">
<?php if($pagination) echo $pagination; ?>
<ul class="articles">
  <?php 
  if(count($articles)) 
  {
      foreach($articles as $val)
      {
      ?>
      <li>
      <h2><?php echo $val->heading; ?></h2> 
      <p><?php echo truncate(strip_tags($val->details),200); ?></p>
      <a href="article_details/<?php echo $val->id."/".$val->slug; ?>" target="_blank">[ Read More ]</a>
      </li>  
      <?php 
      }
  }
  else
  {
      echo '<li><strong>No records found..</strong></li>';
  }
  ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

**articles_details.php (views file)**

```
var_dump($articledetails);
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong. private functions is good if you want only local access , so why local access function should redirect you page that has not access to it?

Comment: as i said im new to codeigniter and was doing it by referring a tutorial.. So what should be the correct way to access it

Comment: If you're new to CI, the absolute BEST thing you can do is to read the official CI documentation from start to finish.  It's more than just reference material, and actually very easy to read/understand.  It's riddled with demos and tutorial examples that you can try yourself as you go along.  Take your time and you'll still get the whole thing done in under 4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a controller named `article_details` or in your main controller , define a function as `article_details` and `index`(as exist) . but Do Not control everything by a function , while you can have lots of it.

So the right way is that you should have a `index` function , and fetch rows then pass it to the view to show it.

in your view :

```
foreach($articles as $i){
        echo '<a href="'.site_url('{your_controller}/article_details/').$i->id.'/'.$val->slug.'" target="_blank">[ Read More ]</a>';
    }
```

And in your controller , define a function named : `article_details` . It will be public and you can handle the article ID and fetch details and pass it to the view.

Answer (score 0):

As CI 2.2.0 , method or functions that starts with an underscore `_`

> "..will not be served via a URL request.."

. 
[have a look here, and find PRIVATE FUNCTIONS](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#what).

The logical question here is why would you want to redirect a `VISIBLE` *controller/method* to a `HIDDEN` one?. you will not be able to access anything since you want in Hidden the first place.

Remove the underscores and change the property to public. If you want int to be accessed correctly.

Or maybe you have a typo or forgot to type something from the tutorial you were following.